# Visualising activity

Tags: data-visualization, dataset

I work for an organisation that provides free activities that benefit people's health. We have a well maintained database that records participation and I am using it in order to research the active population, and their participation levels and trends.

I am trying to show how people use the service over time.

I have been able to show this for a small number of people, by using an XY scatter graph, giving each person a unique number that is plotted on the Y axis, then their activity day is plotted on the X axis (number of days since sign up). What this shows is that activity tends to be clumped (i.e. people do the activity for a short period of time then give up again).

This is interesting, but I would like to be able to show it for a much larger group of people. However, visualising it in this way quickly gets messy for a much larger dataset. I was wondering if you would be able to suggest some alternative ways I could show it.

I am already using a few graphs to show average activity level over time, but what is really interesting here is the 'clumping' of activity which I can't show by aggregating data.

I have shown a few images below that should help with my above explanation.

I will only be able to use free tools or MS Excel to visualise unfortunately.

[image: Small sample - scatter][image: Larger Sample - scatter]

Comment: What about using a drop-down list or filter to show the ones that you want and exclude the others. You can include some statistical summaries in front of each person names in that list to filter based on them too. That would help to have a sense what do you want in the graph and what you want to be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a horizontal stacked bar in Excel to show people's activity days in colour blocks with gaps painted white, like so:

[image: Activity blocks in orange]

It will mean doing some transformations to your data, though, as you'd need two rows for each day with 1 and 0 depending on whether a customer engaged in an activity that day. If you're familiar with VBA it should be possible to do it programmatically.